# Can you access an object-defined property in a private method in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am building out a library that is roughly laid out as follows. There are a couple of variables, an event handler and a method which results in the related event firing. Finally I extend the deal with a property. It goes like this (I've added some `///...` where I've clipped out other code):

```
$.collidR = function (options) {

  /// ...

  var hubName = 'CollidRHub';
  var hubProxy = connection.createHubProxy(hubName);   

  /// ...

  hubProxy.on('registrationComplete', function (username, hasChanges) {
      $(window).triggerHandler(events.onRegistrationComplete, { username: username, hasChanges: hasChanges });
      log(username + " has successfully registered for this entity.");

      // capture current user 
      this._currentUser = username;

      // hook for catching up when user joins after edits
      if (hasChanges) {
          log("There are outstanding changes for this entity...");

      }
  }); 

  /// ...

  this.registerClient = function () {
      /// does some stuff that makes registrationComplete fire
      /// ...
  };

};

Object.defineProperty($.collidR.prototype, "currentUser", {
    get: function () {
        return this._currentUser ? this._currentUser : "";
    }
});
```

Note that above the `this._currentUser = username` bit does not seem to work. I think it's a problem with encapsulation, which is what this question is building towards.

In a separate but related library I create an instance of `collidR`, and I need to respond to an event.  I've got the handler for that set up as follows:

```
$(window).on(collidR.events.onEditorsUpdated, function (e, data) {

  /// ...

  users.forEach(function (user) {
      var currentUser = collidR.currentUser;

      // here, currentUser is always default of ""
      if (user != currentUser) {
          /// ...
      }
  });

});
```

Here is what I am seeing:

1. My `registrationComplete` event fires and the handler is called successfully
2. From a debugger, `this._currentUser` is undefined before the value is set
3. The line `this._currentUser = username` is executed and the value is set
4. When the `onEditorsUpdated` event fires, `collidR.currentUser` is always the default value (an empty string) in my handler

What feels out-of-order is where I define the property -- after the rest of the object. It's as though I'm altering the prototype of the object after I define a method which tries to reference the property...this can't be right.

I've also tried `this.currentUser` (in the internal method), but had the same result.

I had assumed that if the prototype was extended before the internal method was invoked that when I did `var currentUser = collidR.currentUser;` that I would get the value from the property, but it's always an empty string.

Is there a way to register the property earlier?

Is there a correct way to set the value so that I will be able to access it later via the exposed property?

Comment: What is `this` intended to be when you do `this._currentUser`?

Comment: the variable `collidR` in second snippet, is that the instance of `$.collidR` function. i mean did defined it with `collidR = new $.collidR` or a shortcut of $.collidR?

Comment: @Bharath it is an instance defined as you suggest with `var collidR = new $collidR;`.

Comment: if you want to use `this` inside child function. you can use html5 `function(){}.bind(this)` function which will set the scope of function to `this` object

Answer (score 5):

Because `this` in `this._currentUser = username;` isn't what you think it is. The value of `this` in JavaScript depends on how the function was called. I assume that inside the handler, it's now referring to `hubProxy` or some other object other than `collidR`.

*Assuming that your entire plugin's `this` refers to `collidR`* (which I highly suspect isn't, explained in the section after this), what you can do is save the context of that scope into another variable *outside* the handler. That way, you can refer to the outer scope's context via that variable:

```
// Saving this scope's context
var that = this;

hubProxy.on('registrationComplete', function (username, hasChanges) {

  // access _currentUser via the saved context
  that._currentUser = username;

});
```

However, I should warn you about using `this`. Assuming you are creating a plugin, you'd be calling it like `$.collidR({..})`. In this case, the `this` inside the function will refer to `$` (which I assume is jQuery) and [you are attaching some property to the library](http://jsfiddle.net/D6WMY/). It's risky to attach plugin-specific values to a global library as collisions might occur.

I suggest you store it inside a local variable/object instead.

Comment: Yup, basically `this` inside the function refers to the context of the function...

Comment: Thank you @Joseph-the-Dreamer...that makes sense to this old c# boot. :) So is it not possible then to access the property of the instance, rather than the method, from inside the scope of the handler? Or is there a way to return the value of the local variable from the property getter?

Comment: @MisterJames You can access the property of the instance, but you need to remember that JavaScript has function-level scope, not block level scope. So inside the handler, the scope is the handler itself, hence `this` point to this handler, not its container. If you want to simulate encapsulation with JavaScript, I suggest reading Ben Cherry's article on module pattern. Trust me, it's worth the while. If you are on his page, read up on hoisting too :)